# WPF panel rotation?

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation, wpf-controls

I have a custom hexagon menu in wpf and want to rotate it
this is the rotation code

```
 hexagonMenu1.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(i,hexagonMenu1.Hexagon.ContainerRect.Width / 2, hexagonMenu1.Hexagon.ContainerRect.Height / 2);
```

when I call this code more than one it do nothing and panel not rotated , what can i do?
Thanks.

Comment: notice that you create a new rotatetransform at each click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to increase the rotation angle, i.e. your parameter `i`, with each new RenderTransform.

It would also be possible to reuse the existing RenderTransform and increase its [Angle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.angle.aspx) property:

```
hexagonMenu1.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(0, hexagonMenu1.Hexagon.ContainerRect.Width / 2, hexagonMenu1.Hexagon.ContainerRect.Height / 2);
...
double deltaRotation = ...
// do the following for every rotation cycle
((RotateTransform)hexagonMenu1.RenderTransform).Angle += deltaRotation;
```

You might also consider to [animate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx) the rotation angle, thus eliminating the need for looping over an increasing rotation angle:

```
DoubleAnimation animation =
    new DoubleAnimation(360, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

((RotateTransform)hexagonMenu1.RenderTransform).BeginAnimation(
    RotateTransform.AngleProperty, animation);
```

Comment: still rotate first time only when i call it more than one I got nothing no rotation

Comment: Thanks for all finally it's work fine the problem in create new instance form rotatetransform it must be one object for all rotation operation and just increase rotation angle only for each time you want to rotate the shape 
Thanks 4 ALL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to appreciate that the code you have written is not "rotating the hexagon;" it is "setting the rotation for the hegaxon."

What you think your code is doing is: "Rotate 30 degrees.  Rotate another 30 degrees.  Now I am rotated 60 degrees."

In reality, your code is doing this: "Set rotation to 30 degrees.  Set rotation to 30 degrees.  Rotation is set to 30 degrees."

No matter how many times you call your code, it will not result in further rotation.  You need to change the code, so that the value of `i` is different *before* you set the rotation.